# How do you merge differences in file-level differences in Team Explorer within VS 2015?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015, merge, git-merge

I apologise if this has been asked before, however, I can't find a solution that applies to VS 2015.

I have to merge two branches together.  Most of the work is fine, however, I have a specific XAML file that has a conflict.  The problem is that the file has changes in both versions that need to be kept.  So, what I need to do is compare the two files and selectively specify which diff changes to keep.

After I initiated the Merge in Visual Studio Team Explorer, I see the conflict on the conflict screen.  When I double-click on the file, it shows me options to either keep the target or take the source.  I can click on a "Diff" link to see the difference, however, this is just static display of the textual differences.

How can I merge these changes?  I don't mind doing it manually, one code line at a time, but I'm completely stumped at figuring out how to do this.

Can someone help?  How can I resolve my conflicts at the file-level?

Also, if it helps, we are using Github and not a TFS server.  I don't see why that would be a big issue because this type of fix should be just an IDE change, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're on the Resolve Conflicts page in Team Explorer, there should be a Merge button for each file, above the Compare Files link, which is above the Take Source / Keep Target links.

Click the Merge button to open a 3-way merge window: Source in upper left, Target in upper right, and Result below. You can pick and choose which changes to keep with the checkboxes, and manually edit the result if needed. Click Accept Merge when finished.

Comment: I've been making this to hard, for too long.  This is exactly the answer.  With a lack of documentation, I've skirted clicking that merge button, assuming I should be able to do this from the 'diff' comparison links.  Thank you.